# Redirect and Print Page Onload using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to redirect(window.location or window.replace) to new url and on loading of that page want to print that page (.print()) using jquery.

I have tried

```
  window.location.replace(url).print();
```

But it just redirect page and wan't print the page,
Any Idea ?

Comment: The question is, do you have access to the code of the page you are redirecting to?

Comment: @Kinduser yes i have ,all access to whole site,and just want to redirect to anothe specific page on specific button click

Comment: @freshbm thanks for support but your code just redirect to url i want to print() that too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first file, add following script:

```
<body>
<a href="yourPageThatYouWantRedirectTo.html" onclick='func()'>Click and redirect</a>

<script>
function func(){
  localStorage.setItem('redirected', true);
}
</script>
</body>
```

And in your another file, which you are redirecting to:

```
window.onload = function(){
  var wasRedirected = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('redirected'));
  if (wasRedirected == true) {
    window.print();
    localStorage.clear();
  }
}
```

Comment: धन्यवाद, Running but can i use better than this ? like   `window.location.open(url).print();` problem with this, it opens in new tab

Comment: @Priyank57 You want to open the page in new tab? Or in the same window?

Comment: In the same tab i have done that by passing one extra parameter(print) in redirecting url .

Comment: Let's chat over here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135444/priyank57

Answer (score 2):

Add the `print()` to your onload-function in the site you want to print.

```
 window.location.replace(url)
```

redirects to a site directly. so `print()` is never called.

If this is not possible you can use the following code:

```
function printExternal(url) {
    var printWindow = window.open( url, 'Print', 'left=200, top=200, width=950, height=500, toolbar=0, resizable=0');
    printWindow.addEventListener('load', function(){
        printWindow.print();
        printWindow.close();
    }, true);
}
```

Comment: i want to print page only when page is redirected from this page,so cant use print() on load.